# How to extract column names from spark sql Column?

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I am very new to the Scala world, and am stuck at a problem for quite some time now, so seeking out your help!

I have a variable defined as `Column (someExpression)`, for example:

```
val someExpr = Column( "concat( col(\"name\") && col(\"address\") )")
```

Is there a way I can get the names of the columns used in the expression inside `Column()` ? I tried to playaround with UnresolvedAttribute but wasn't able to make it work for my usecase.

I'd be happy to provide any extra information, code samples if my question isn't clear in the current form.

Thank you so much!

Comment: why are you trying to do this? Is this an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: U want an array  of thinsg between the "\"  \""   ?

Comment: @thebluephantom I want all the column-names that have been referenced in the expression. 
Once I get the list of all the column names, I would want to do something with it, eg show it on some dashboard.

Comment: @mck Not really an xy problem, I want to extract all the existing column names which have been used to generate this new Column. 
Once I get the list of all the column names, I would want to display it on some dashboard.

Comment: Is it a variable or part of a dataframe?

Comment: @thebluephantom the expression inside ```Column``` consist of dataframe column names. Basically, ```Column``` is used to create a new column by performing some operations on other columns. For example, in the question, a new column is created that concatenates the name and address columns from an existing dataset. What I want, is to be able to extract all the column names of a dataset that have been used inside the ```Column``` expression.

Comment: So you juts want a list from a val? That's what I understand.